# Puppeteer Hangs In Headless Mode

Tags: javascript, timeout, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

My Puppeteer script is running in headless mode and it's timing out.

I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong. The script runs fine locally, but when I'm running in headless mode it always times out.

I've read online that could be due to the script failing to load an external javascript source? Has anyone else run into this problem, and able to help out?

Here's my setup function for my Puppeteer instance:

```
 setUpPuppeteer: async () => {
    const headless = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    const browser = await pupeteer.launch({
      headless,
      devtools: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox' ]
    });
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage(); // Create new instance of puppet

    page.on('error', err => {
      logger.error('Puppeteer error.', err);
    });

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000);

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      await page.setRequestInterception(true); // Optimize (no stylesheets, images)...
      page.on('request', request => {
        if (['image', 'stylesheet'].includes(request.resourceType())) {
          request.abort();
        } else {
          request.continue();
        }
      });
    }

    return {browser: context, page};
  },
```

Comment: if devtools is true, the headless option will get set to false. set the devtools to false and try again.

Answer (score 4):

```
setUpPuppeteer: async () => {
    const headless = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    const browser = await pupeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      devtools: true,
      args: [
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--disable-gpu'
            ]
    });
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage(); // Create new instance of puppet

    page.on('error', err => {
      logger.error('Puppeteer error.', err);
    });

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000);

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      await page.setRequestInterception(true); // Optimize (no stylesheets, images)...
      page.on('request', request => {
        if (['image', 'stylesheet'].includes(request.resourceType())) {
          request.abort();
        } else {
          request.continue();
        }
      });
    }

    return {browser: context, page};
  },
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)

Comment: Thanks. your args really helped me out. I had a script it worked perfectly on windows10 and OSX but wouldnt work on linux. I couldnt figure it out. It just kept hanging where it would run smoothly otherwise.  but after i added your args it worked!  So Thank You!

Comment: `devtools: true` automatically sets `headless` to `false`. That is certainly not what OP or people who end up on this page wanted to see.